# Scala, waiting to execute foreach on parallel collection

Tags: scala, foreach, parallel-collections

I have code like below

```
    val g = new Graph(vertices)

        //Firts part

        (1 to vertices).par.foreach( i => g + new Vertex(i))

       //Second part

          for (i <- 1 to edges) {
            val data = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
            val d = data.split(" ")
            val v1 = d(0).toInt
            val v2 = d(1).toInt
            val length = d(2).toInt
            g+(v1, v2, length)
        }
```

I want to execute first and second part of code sequentially.
At present for loop run before the all Vertex have added to g.
In code + (plus) define add new instance of Vertex to MutableList.

I'am new in scala, please help

Comment: Can you show Vertex and Graph implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution. I read more about add new elements to collection parallel and it isn't thread save. I replaced MutableList to fixedsize array, and I add new element by index.

Some code below:

```
class Graph(val end: Int) {

  private val vertices : Array[Vertex] = new Array[Vertex](end)

  def +(index: Int, v: Vertex): Unit = {
    vertices(index) = v
  }  

  (...)
}

     //Firts part
      (1 to vertices).par.foreach( i => g + (i-1,new Vertex(i))) //add new vertex to array by index
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallel collection only parallelises the computation for the collection. The second part of the computation where you add edges should happen after the adding of the vertices.

What I would assume is that may be from parsing there are some vertices which does not exists in the vertices at all, may be some empty space or something like that.

I am not sure about what goes on while adding the vertices to the graph but the foreach on parallel should be careful if the operation should be free of side-effect. Please see [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html#side-effecting-operations) for more information. May be this is not even relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each call in the following

```
new Thread(new Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    //Code part here:
  }
}).start()
```

You also need to ensure that the your `Graph` implementation is thread safe as you will have two threads modifying it concurrently.

It doesn't look like you're returning anything from either part but if you were you could use a `Future` instead. See [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) for details.